# Need to update values in an array but keep the original values to update it again

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I want to update a recipe to change the amount of each ingredient. Everything works fine when I put in the first value but after that, it updates against the updated values not the original values. I tried setting up a 2nd array to hold the original values and then exchange them but it didn't work. Here is a live version of script http://jsfiddle.net/a8YTa/3/. I hope seeing the jsfiddle makes my question clear.

Edit: Here is the version where I tried to set up a second array with the original values and it didn't work http://jsfiddle.net/a8YTa/5/

Edit: As requested here is the code in question:

```
  var numIngred = document.getElementsByClassName('ingred');
  var initServ = document.getElementsByClassName('servnumber')[0].innerHTML;

  var newServ = document.getElementById('newserv');

  var divider = 0;
  function changeServ(){
     divider = initServ/newServ.value;
     var i=0;
    for(i=0; i<numIngred.length; i++){ 
        numIngred[i].innerHTML = numIngred[i].innerHTML/divider;
    }

  }

  newServ.oninput = changeServ;
```

html which has the original values:

```
 Serves: <span class="servnumber">8</span><br/><br/>
 How many would you like to serve?:<input id="newserv" />
 <br/><br/>
 <span class="ingred">1</span> Apple <br/>
 <span class="ingred">3</span> Peaches <br/>
 <span class="ingred">.5</span> Pineapples <br/>
 <span class="ingred">2</span>lbs nuts <br/>
 <span class="ingred">6</span> small peppers <br/>
```

Comment: Can you post the appropriate pieces of code here? If someone comes to read this in the future and your jsfiddle has gone, the question and answers will be impossible to follow.

Comment: Sure, I can post it but the correct answer is also a link to another jsfiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your solution is that your array consists of *references to objects* in the page:

```
var numIngred = document.getElementsByClassName('ingred'); //array of HTML elements
```

So, when you do `numIngred[index].innerHTML`, it access the current value of the property.

To solve this, you just have to create a new array to store the *actual value of innerHTML*, not a reference to the objects:

```
var defaultValues = [];

for(var i = 0; i < numIngred.length; i++) {
    defaultValues[i] = numIngred[i].innerHTML;
}
```

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/a8YTa/7/

Comment: Hey I know this is a separate question but any idea why this isn't returning correctly http://jsfiddle.net/a8YTa/8/ ? It shouldn't show decimal points for whole numbers but that only works if the input is under 10.

Comment: @AdeptOfHermes: Because the modulus is not returning 0. To see this, alert the result of `defaultValues[i] % divider`. This is because javascript use floating point, instead of decimal number. There are some ways around this, try goggling it ;)

Comment: Please add snippets of code into your answer to show what you mean. If the Q & A jsfiddles disappear sometime, this will be uninformative.

Comment: Yeah I noticed it wasn't coming back 0 also so I ended up doing this:
if ((num - Math.floor(num)) <.01 ) {
                numIngred[i].innerHTML = Math.floor(num);
            } else {
                numIngred[i].innerHTML = num.toFixed(2);
            }
It's kind of dirty but it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are calculating your ingredients from the last array, thus your recipe is soon going to become a big mush. :)

You need to create an array which contains the original ingredients and remains unchanged and then calculate your new values from this array when a value (Amount to serve) is entered into the textbox.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know I didn't show that in this version of the fiddle but I did try to do that and it didn't work. In fact I mentioned that in the question. If you could illustrate how to do that correctly that would be appreciated. Edit: This how I tried to do it and it didn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/a8YTa/5/

Answer (score 0):

Re. your comment above:
origingred is the same as numingred. It's a (live) node list containing the same (live) span.ingred elements. Changing them in numingred changes origingred too.

What you need is a real static data source.

You could either store youre ingredient in a real array, like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/EmWeG/

or use extra attributes in your markup:

```
<span class="ingred" data-orig="1">1</span>
```

then base your calculation on

```
parseFloat(numIngred[i].getAttribute('data-orig'))
// i.e. numIngred[i].innerHTML = <the above> / divider;
```